# Recursive definition solution

Tags: java

im studying for my final exam from the text book. I need an answer for this question since i couldn't solve it.

1)Write a recursive definition of the function multiply(int a, int b) that takes two integers and return the result of their multiplication.

I answered:

```
Multiply(a, b) :
0 - if a or b is equal to zero.   (I got -1 here. Reason written: only 1)
a * b - (I didn't know what to write here)
```

2)
Write a recursive method that takes a linked list of integers and returns the sum of it's elements.

My solution was:

```
int sumList(Node<Integer> list) {

    int temp = list.getInfo();

    if(temp == null) {
        return 0;

    } else {
        return temp + sumList(temp.getNext);
    }
}
```

I fixed it, i think:

```
 public int sumList(Node<Integer> list) {

    Node<Integer> temp = list;

    if(temp == null) {
        return 0;

    } else {
        return temp.getInfo() + sumList(temp.getNext());
    }
}
```

Is the solution for question 2 right?

Comment: No, it's not right. It doesn't even compile. Why don't you compile and run your code, and see if it produces the right result?

Comment: @user2272227 Google it plenty of recursive method samples are out there !

Comment: @JBNizet that's the reason, bcz for my exam i can't test, it's a written exam. I need help finding the right code and why it's wrong by looking at it.

Comment: Then compile  and run it, understand the compiler and execution errors, and make sure not to write code that would produce the same errors anymore.

Comment: Well, write it on paper, then type it into the computer to *check* it, instead of asking us...

Comment: Please add the definition of your `Node` class, or at least a description what `getInfo()` and `getNext` are. Also, your method is called `SumList` (upper case) while you call `sumList` (lower case). Is that a typo?

Comment: @Carsten getInfo() returns info of the node. and getNext() returns the link to the next node. typo yes.

Comment: @user2272227 then you are also missing the parenthesis for `getNext()`

Comment: @TecHunter see my edit, posted a fixed code, is it right?

Comment: @user2272227 I guess not. Syntaxically it's better but still. temp should be an `Node<Integer> temp = list.getNext();` I will let you think about it, you stop when you don't have a next. No need to declare a temp variable for `list`

Comment: @TecHunter still dont get why it should be .getNext()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a working recursive solution you need a *base case*, for example `a == 0`, and then work yourself down towards the base case by recursively calling yourself.

The solution for question 1 could be something along the lines of this, that decreases the `a` argument until it reaches `0`:

```
int multiply(int a, int b) {
    if (a == 0 || b == 0) {
        return 0;
    } 
    return b + multiply(a - 1, b);
}
```

For example, `multiply(2, 5)` would become `5 + multiply(1, 5)` -> `5 + 5 + multiply(0, 5)` -> `5 + 5 + 0`.

Note that this particular solution doesn't work for negative numbers, but you get the idea. You should be able to easily add support for that yourself.

Comment: Actually you don't need the second `if`.

Comment: Could you help explain the last part, i understood the first 2 but the part with return b + multiply. didnt quite understand it.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: True. I got stuck in multiplication thinking.

Comment: @Keppil you should add `if(a<0) {return -1 * multiply(-a,b);}`

Comment: @MarcoForberg: Yes, I left that out, but that would make it work for negatives too.

Comment: @MarcoForberg i think no need, since it checks if a is zero?

Comment: @Keppil could u help explain the negative part posted by marco?

Comment: @MarcoForberg No need of over-complicating things. Simple math calculation can remove `if` statement: http://pastebin.com/zxsv0amN

Comment: @MarcoForberg Since it's educational example it's better to use math than huge (speaking in general) branching with `if/else`. In real-world nobody would do recursive multiplication.

Comment: @user2272227: He just changes the call `multiply(-3, 5)` to `-1 * multiply(3, 5)`.

Comment: @TecHunter have a look at the last part of the answer and the comments here

Comment: @MarcoForberg Yeah I saw that but the answer should be edited accordingly

Comment: @TecHunter: I don't think it should, I think it is better if some of it is left out.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is for exam preparation, I don't want to give you the code for doing this. Instead I will give you some ideas.

For the question no 1. Since multiplication is repeated summation, you can use that as the base for recursion here.

If you want to find 3 * 4, use recursion to calculate and return 4 + 4 + 4.

In other words, you can see a pattern emerge below.

> 4 * 3 = 4 + (4 * 2)
>
> 4 * 3 = 4 + 4 + (4 * 1)

Comment: @TecHunter and silver, ok basically id be doing something like this: return b + multiply(a - 1, b); since someone posted it down, but i don't understand why the a-1 is needed?

Comment: OH! the a-1 is to drop it to 0 until each time we need it to be multiplied is over. For example, 5*5, it will keep adding 5 until a is 0 then it will stop meaning it added 5,5,5,5,5 as needed 5 times! Correct?

Comment: (a - 1) is to do the next step in the calculation.

mul(4,3)
mul(4,2)
mul(4,1)
etc..

Comment: I'm sure you got it now. Just apply what you learned in recursion. you need to find the recursion method and the end case.

Comment: @user2272227 correct. Recursion is always about stop conditions, argument changes and assuming the rest of the operation is already done by recursion. I mean, given a `multiply(a,n)` you just need to consider how you would use the next call `multiply(a,n-1)` in the current call. Here is adding `a` to next call. Generally arguments change as counter or collections modification

Answer (score 0):

A) well, you *really* need to reread that chapter on recursion.

The mathematical principle is this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction

and the Wikipedia article will step you through a much more complicated task.

B) No, it won't compile at all. There are multiple syntax errors.

Try using a Java compiler for excersising your programming skills.